# How to: Setting a constant speed of a motor related to a push down distance of a trigger

Tags: animation, modifiers

I need to animate a powertool and would like to animate the motor.
I know how to set up a driver with constant speed so it's turning forever, but:

I would like to influence the motor speed (rpm) by pressing the trigger. So when I'm creating my animation I would like to touch the trigger only.

For example:

If the trigger is not pressed at all motor speed is 0 rpm

If the trigger is pressed in by 3.9mm the motor speed is 2700 rpm (which is 16200° in 30 fps)

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to *Item > Transform > Rotation* on the motor.
- <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on X,Y, or Z rotation and choose *Add Driver*.
- As the expression, do something like `frame * (var * 360)`. With `var`, set the Object to be the trigger, and choose the Type to be Y
  Location.
- Press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to begin animation- speed of rotation is constant, but changes when the trigger moves.

You may need to adjust *360 to get it exactly right, but that's how you do it

Comment: here we go! thanks :) I forgot the "frame*" in my expression I had already

Comment: Here's what that looks like: https://i.postimg.cc/Y2yJzJqh/ezgif-com-gif-maker.gif